# Show category names in breadcrumb in product page magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, product, page, breadcrumbs

How can i show full category names in breadcrumb on product details page.
Currently it is coming like https://www.screencast.com/t/5o9uZEu8xnV
I want like this https://www.screencast.com/t/1pfZkoVSWLov

Answer (score 0):

To display category name in bread cums you have to override block **breadcrumbs**  of default magento to your module.

You can override block with reference block using layout file. like below.

add layout file **catalog_product_view.xml** in your module Path should be: `app\code\Vendor\Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_view.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page>
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="breadcrumbs" remove="true" />
    <referenceContainer name="page.top">
        <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Crumbblock" name="crumbs" as="crumbs" template="Vendor_Module::crumbs.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

[Check this reference link for more details.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/281117/magento-2-how-to-show-categories-name-in-breadcrumbs-in-some-conditions)

Comment: will this show categories, sub cat everything? have you tried this code?

Comment: This is working but creating problem when one product belongs to more than one category

Comment: it was worked fine for me.. there might be a problem if you are using custom theme. and also code may not work due to magento different version. so you have to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you install [this extension](https://github.com/EaDesgin/magento2-full-path-category-product-breadcrumb).

After Install extension run below commands :-

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

After you install you got this error like :-

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in E:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator.php on line 63
```

**How to solve this error follow this step**

1.) Go to this path :- **`app/code/Eadesigndev/FullBreadcrumbs/etc/adminhtml`** and Open the **`system.xml`** file.

2.) Change this code like :-

In section tag above add this code

```
<tab id="eadesign_extensions" translate="label" sortOrder="2000">
  <label>Custom Tab</label>
</tab>
```

**`UPDATE`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="eadesign_extensions" translate="label" sortOrder="2000">
            <label>Custom Tab</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="ea_fullbreadcrumbs" sortOrder="150" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                 showInStore="1">
            <label>Full Breadcrumbs</label>
            <tab>eadesign_extensions</tab>
            <resource>Eadesigndev_FullBreadcrumbs::fullbreadcrumbs_configuration</resource>
            <group id="fullbreadcrumbs" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="text" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                   showInStore="1">
                <label>Full Breadcrumbs</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" sortOrder="10" type="select" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="bad_categories" translate="label comment" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1"
                       showInStore="1">
                    <label>Exluded categories</label>
                    <comment>Enter the IDs of the categories that will be excluded from Full Breadcrumbs. ex:
                        4,12,15,14,78
                    </comment>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

And After you chnage run below command :-

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

Thanks .

Comment: Does this work when you have one product in multiple categories?? which category path it takes?

Comment: Hello @StevenHarris Yes, working one product in multiple categories and i kindly  suggest you install and check

Comment: Hi, what to change in system.xml please explain properly

Comment: you open this file `Eadesigndev/FullBreadcrumbs/etc/adminhtml and Open the system.xml` and section tag above add this code `<tab id="eadesign_extensions" translate="label" sortOrder="2000">
  <label>Custom Tab</label>
</tab>`.

Comment: And solve the issues accept answer so useful other community .

Comment: Still did not understand. can you please share system.xml entire code over here

Comment: i have update my answer Please check